# Drupal 7 global javascript variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7

In my Drupal 7 installation, I have 2 separate JavaScript files that are loaded by my sub-themes (base and admin sub-theme) - I don't know if this is useful information or not, but:

What if I want to define a JavaScript variable in the first js file that is loaded and use it in the second one? How should I define it?

Basically, the question could be: How to define global JavaScript variables in a Drupal environment?

I am using jQuery.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

First js file:

```
var myOwnVar;

(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        myOwnVar = 1;
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Second js file:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log(myOwnVar);
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: did u find ans to this problem, I am having same issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use Drupal.settings.

The values can be globally accessed across the JavaScript functions.

You can pass variables from your PHP to JS...

```
drupal_add_js(array('YOURMODULE' => array('SOMEVARIABLE' => 'woohoo')), 'setting');
```

Then access the variable in your JS function...

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.YOURMODULE = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      // You can access the variable by using Drupal.settings.SOMEVARIABLE
      alert(Drupal.settings.YOURMODULE.SOMEVARIABLE);

    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Please refer to http://drupal.org/node/172169#variablesandarrays

*"Variables should not be defined in the global scope; try to define them in a local function scope at all costs. All variables should be declared at the beginning of a function."*

Alternatively, the following outside of any closures will work but should be avoided.

```
var SOMEVARIABLE = SOMEVALUE;

(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.YOURMODULE = {
```

Comment: I am playing right now with the Drupal.settings - but still this does not answer my question. I want to SET a global variable in JavaScript and GET it in JavaScript as well. Not through PHP.

Comment: This is 'the Drupal way', otherwise please refer to comments above.

Comment: I can't believe there is no simple way for doing that, without the use of PHP. Isn't there a way to set Drupal.settings from JS?

Comment: Yes I have read the doc already. Even if it says we should avoid doing this, doesn't mean we can't.

Comment: "Alternatively, the following outside of any closures will work but should be avoided." - As far as I tested, it doesn't.

Comment: Are themes enabled? Are JS files defined in .info and checked they are being loaded?

Comment: Yes they are. Both of them. And they are loaded, and I know in which order they load.

Comment: My first js file starts with var myOwnVar = true; - within my second js file, in the document.ready function, if I log myOwnVar -> ReferenceError : myOwnVar is not defined